# React project using webpack. Reference error: React is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have browsed through other threads but didn't manage to find the answer. 
Here is my setup:
[image]

In package.json:

```
{
  "name": "myr",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack -d --watch",
    "build": "webpack -p",
    "start": "webpack -d ; node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "body-parser": "~1.17.1",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "debug": "~2.6.3",
    "express": "~4.15.2",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "morgan": "~1.8.1",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
    "webpack": "^2.6.1"
  }
}
```

In webpack.config.js:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, '');
var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'app');

var config = {
  entry: APP_DIR + '/index.jsx',
  output: {
    path: BUILD_DIR,
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module : {
    loaders : [
      {
        test : /\.jsx?/,
        include : APP_DIR,
        loader : 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};

module.exports = config;
```

In index.jsx:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import AwesomeComponent from './AwesomeComponent.jsx';

class App extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <p> Hello React!</p>
        <AwesomeComponent />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementByID('app'));
```

And the console output from the browser says:
[image]

I tried to look into `bundle.js` but there is not much help.
I browsed through other threads and couldn't find the answer.

React is there in node_modules and package.json

Comment: Just a heads up - your image links are broken so we can't see exactly what's going on. Please fix those!

Comment: You image links aren't working

Comment: Images aren't working.

Comment: They are working for me for some reasons.

[repo structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEfFD.png)

[console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntu5N.png)

Comment: @HungNguyen Can you post your package.json file here as well?

Comment: Can you modify your babel-loader to this one.
{
    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
    exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
    loader: 'babel-loader'
   }

Comment: And create a .babelrc file with this content {
 presets: ['react', 'es2015']
}

Comment: @HungNguyen or first just change the test condition to test: /\.(js|jsx)$/.

Comment: @VivekN I tried your suggestions but it didn't fix the problem

Comment: Is this on github?

Comment: @HungNguyen Please add this in your webpack config file, so that we can better debug the code.
devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',

Comment: As VivekN I would remove query from webpack and add .babelrc. Also try npm install. Use plain webpack in package.json

Comment: https://github.com/Hank-TNguyen/React-web

I just pushed the project here

Comment: Try this test expression `test : /\.jsx?$/,`

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri the problem still persists